# Sweetalert closes popup on confirm to call api request

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

My popups gets close after click on confirm and again open a new popup that shows success. There is a huge gap where no loading process show.

I have read the documentation of the ajax request on [sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#ajax-requests). It work so perfectly there, the button shows loading while the API is being called. I am trying to do the same. I want to delete request where I first open a swal to Confirm and if yes it will call the api without closing popup.

```
removeSession: function(sessionId){
    var _this = this;
    var errormessage = 'Error! Session not delete';
    var callData = {}
    callData["sessionId"] = 0;
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, the session will be removed.",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            app.apiCustomPost(apiController_data, "delete", callData , function(res){

                if(res.status=="success") {

                    swal(res.message, {
                        icon: "success",
                      });
                      _this.init();

                } else {

                    swal(errormessage, {
                        icon: "error"
                    });                     

                }
            }); 
        } else {
            swal(errormessage, {
                icon: "error"
            });             
        }
      });
},
```

Please help me to correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this finally. There is magic on [button](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#buttons) properties of sweet alert. We need to describe closeModal value to either true or false in order to close the modal or not to close.

Now the button show on loading...

Hope this helps someone.

```
removeSession: function(sessionId){
    var _this = this;
    var errormessage = 'Error! Session not delete';
    var callData = {}
    callData["sessionId"] = 0;
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, the session will be removed.",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: {

              cancel: {
                text: "Cancel",
                value: false,
                visible: true,
                className: "",
                closeModal: true,
              },
              confirm: {
                text: "OK",
                value: true,
                visible: true,
                className: "",
                closeModal: false
              }

        },
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((isConfirm) => {
        if (!isConfirm){ return false;}


            app.apiCustomPost(apiController_data, "delete", callData , function(res){

                if(res.status=="success") {

                        swal(res.message, {
                            icon: "success",
                          });

                          _this.init();

                } else {
                        swal(errormessage, {
                            icon: "error"
                        });                     

                }
            }); 

      });

},
```

Comment: It does not work for me!!  By using buttons it is only showing one default button.